# how to resolve the problem of ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error with web flutter

Tags: php, flutter, http, post

i got a problem when i try to send data with http.post with web navigator, returning all time the error:
ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error... of course with using flutter

the code is:

```
String dataurl = "https://www.portalcri.com.br/st10sports/admin/webserver2/cadastro_campeonatos.php";
    var map =  <String, dynamic>{};
    map['modo'] = 'pesquisar';
    map['status2'] = '';

    var result = await http.post ( Uri.parse(dataurl), body: map, headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});
    if (result.statusCode == 200) {
      print (result.body);

      final data = jsonDecode(result.body);

      print (data);

      for (dynamic item in data) {
        setState(() {
          listaItens.add(TabelaCampeonatos.fromJson(item));
        });
      }

      setState(() {
        carregandoItens = false;
        semRegistros = false;
      });
    }
```

php backend code already have the headers:

a real solution seems not exists, someone can help me.
just remember then, that was working yet 2 days before.

Comment: what is the full error message?

Comment: When testing I can see that the url is not returning valid JSON ~ it returns a string prefixed with `modo = pesquisar`

Comment: `that was working yet 2 days before`...have a look at things that have changed, then.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is related to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), a security feature that restricts how resources on a web page can be requested from another domain. When your Flutter app is trying to make a request to a different domain, the browser blocks the request because it violates the same-origin policy.

#### Debugging Solution

For debugging purposes, you can disable the same-origin policy in Chrome. This will allow you to make requests to a different domain from your Flutter app. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Navigate to the directory of your Flutter project.
3. Run the following command:

```bash
flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"
```

This will start your Flutter app in Chrome with the same-origin policy disabled.

Please note that this is a workaround for debugging and should not be used in a production environment. The same-origin policy is a security feature that prevents malicious scripts on one page from obtaining access to sensitive data on another web page. Disabling it can expose your app to security risks.

#### Production Solution

The best solution is to configure the server to include the necessary CORS headers in its responses. This tells the browser that it's okay to make requests to this server from a different domain. The server should include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its responses, with the value set to the domain of your Flutter app.

Here's an example of how you can set this up in a Node.js server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

// Your routes here

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'));
```

In this example, the `cors` middleware is used to automatically include the necessary CORS headers in all responses.

However, if you don't have control over the server's configuration, you can use a proxy to add the necessary headers. This is a workaround and should not be used in production. For production, the server should be configured to include the necessary headers.

There are several online services that can act as a CORS proxy, such as cors.sh. You can use these services by prepending the URL of the service to the URL of your API request. For example:

```dart
String dataurl = "https://cors.sh/?https://www.portalcri.com.br/st10sports/admin/webserver2/cadastro_campeonatos.php";
```

This will make the request to the API through the cors.sh proxy, which will add the necessary CORS headers to the response.

Please note that using a CORS proxy can expose your data to the proxy provider, so it's not recommended for sensitive data.

Sources:

- [CORS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- [CORS middleware for Express](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)
- [cors.sh](https://cors.sh/)
- [How to write a CORS proxy with Node.js](https://dev.to/decker67/write-your-own-cors-proxy-with-nodejs-in-no-time-30f9)

Comment: Debugging Solution work as well, thanks so much!

Comment: if i dit a Production solution, i will don't need do run tests with a Debugging solution?

Comment: and where i will conifg a Production solution? in the file php on server? or in the server php?